# EditText with inputType: textEmailAddress not able to type text using Espresso

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-espresso

My xml has an EditText:

```xml
<EditText
android:id="@+id/et_email"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_padding_size_small"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_envelope"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_envelope"
android:drawablePadding="4dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:hint="@string/email_hint"
android:maxLines="1"
android:textColorHint="@color/colorHintText"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
```

Now I was writing UI tests using the Espresso library and it cannot type text into this `EditText` using `typeText()` or `typeTextIntoFocusedView()` and my test method is:

```java
 @Test
    public void onSubmitClickedWithAnInvalidEmail(){
        onView(withId(R.id.et_email)).perform(scrollTo(), click(), typeText("test")); //invalid email
        onView(withId(R.id.btn_submit)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.et_email)).check(matches(hasErrorText(mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getString(R.string.invalid_email_prompt))));
    }
```

The test runs but cannot type into the email edittext. It gets stuck after scrolling to and clicking on the `EditText`. One thing that I noticed is that my email addresses are suggested on the email `EditText` by google in a `Spinner` looking thing. I strongly think that is the reason why espresso is not able to type into the `EditText`.

The message that I get in the Run is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not request layout for 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Root:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@d881111, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@d881111, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string={(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302f8
fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
pfl=FORCE_DRAW_STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params={(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302f8
fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
pfl=FORCE_DRAW_STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}}
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.waitForRootToBeReady(RootViewPicker.java:111)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.pickRootView(RootViewPicker.java:149)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:91)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:77)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:37)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:27)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:63)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:223)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:65)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:155)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**EDIT:**

> Test method

```java
@Test
    public void onSubmitClickedWithAnInvalidEmail() {
        onView(withId(R.id.et_email)).perform(scrollTo(), typeText("test")); //invalid email
        onView(withId(R.id.btn_submit)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.et_email)).check(matches(hasErrorText(mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getString(R.string.invalid_email_prompt))));
    }
```

Error Log:

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'type text(test)' on view 'with id: com.example.myapp:id/et_email'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:86)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:87)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:59)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:322)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:178)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:119)
at com.exmple.myapp.activities.ForgotPasswordActivityTest.onSubmitClickedWithAnInvalidEmail(ForgotPasswordActivityTest.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2337)
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.InjectEventSecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
at androidx.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.injectKeyEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:119)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.EventInjector.injectKeyEvent(EventInjector.java:88)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl$2.call(UiControllerImpl.java:192)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl$2.call(UiControllerImpl.java:189)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.injectInputEvent(IInputManager.java:575)
at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:880)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.injectKeyEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:113)
... 9 more
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
at com.android.server.input.InputManagerService.injectInputEventInternal(InputManagerService.java:627)
at com.android.server.input.InputManagerService.injectInputEvent(InputManagerService.java:601)
at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub.onTransact(IInputManager.java:143)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)
```

Please suggest some workaround or point if I am doing something wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the `typeText()` is blocked by the **Google Autofill Service**. And removing `typeText()` and using `replaceText()` actually works here. But the thing you would want to do is to disable Google Autofill Service from the Settings of your device.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `click` action:

```
onView(withId(R.id.et_email)).perform(scrollTo(), typeText("test"));
```

The `click` and `typeText` actions don't go well together. When the `typeText` action is being performed, it will tap to focus on the `EditText` before it injects string. So having both actions together will result two single-clicks, and may trigger contextual menu on some devices, which prevents Espresso to inject strings.

If `typeText` only still pops contextual menu, then alternatively use [ViewActions.replaceText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#replaceText(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Hey @Aaron No luck with removing the `click()` method on `perform()`. It still can't type into that edittext.
 The error that I get is 
`Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'type text(test)' on view 'with id: com.example.myapp:id/et_email'.`

Comment: It looks like you're getting a different error now. Do you have a longer error log? You're getting a `PerformException` maybe because you're calling the action on a non-editable field, and in this case I assume it's `TextInputLayout`?  If the id `et_email` is a `TextInputLayout` or other type of container then you should change the id to its `EditText`.

Comment: I do have a longer error log. No my `et_email` is not a `TextInputLayout`. It is an `EditiText` as you can see in my original question. I am gonna paste my error log in an edit.

Comment: I see, I guess alternatively you could try [ViewActions.replaceText](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/action/ReplaceTextAction?hl=en), which it simply sets the text without tapping on the field.

Comment: Yes that actually makes the test pass and the error text display is validated. But does this really replicate users typing onto this `EditText`?

Comment: Not really, but we will have to accept the limitation of the test framework. There are many other `ViewActions` are also doing the same without mimicking user interactions. It can depend on the test devices or emulator, in this case, it pops context menu as soon as you tap on the field, which prevent Espresso injecting the string, hence the `InjectEventSecurityException `.